# Drawing / Editing a line in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to draw and edit multiple lines on iOS. Each line has a UIView at each end acting as handles so once the line is drawn a user can drag each end and the line will redraw.

Im currently using a UIBezierPath to draw a CAShapelayer on the view. The issue I have is working the best way to then draw another one and which ever line is tapped on the user can edit this one.

Does anyone have any ideas about the best way for this? Is CAShapelayer the best option?

Video Link that might show better what I'm trying to achieve.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rpt2azrs3uk6vr/Line%20Example.mov?dl=0

An example of the code I have done so far is below:

//Drawing a Line
Here I create a path from two touch points and the draw a CAShapeLayer on the view. I also create a custom object 'Line' to store the path and shapelayer.

```
-(void)DrawLineFrom:(CGPoint)pointA to:(CGPoint)pointB
{
    NSLog(@"Drawing line X:%f Y:%f - X:%f Y:%f", pointA.x, pointA.y, pointB.x, pointB.y);

    UIBezierPath* path = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    [path moveToPoint:pointA];
    [path addLineToPoint:pointB];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(pointB.x, pointB.y+2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(pointA.x, pointA.y+2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:pointA];
    [path closePath];
    currentLine.bPath = path;

    if (!shapeLayer)
    {
        shapeLayer = [LineLayer layer];
        [shapeLayer setFrame:self.view.frame];
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor; //etc...
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0; //etc...
        shapeLayer.parent = currentLine;
        currentLine.shapeLayer = shapeLayer;

        [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    }
    else
    {
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    }

    [self ExitDrawMode];

}
```

//Creating a Handle
This creates the two views at either end and adds the Long Press Gesture.

```
-(HandleView *)MakeLineHandleForPoint:(int)point atLocation:(CGPoint)loc
{
    HandleView *pointView = [[HandleView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(loc.x-10, loc.y-10, 20, 20)];
    pointView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    pointView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *LP = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLp:)];
    [pointView addGestureRecognizer:LP];
    LP.delegate = self;
    LP.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;
    pointView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    pointView.tag = point;
    pointView.lineParent = currentLine;

    return pointView;
}
```

Finally the gesture is handled here. This works fine however will always move the last line drawn. Even if I have selected the first one.

-(void)handleLp:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint loc = [sender locationInView:self.view];

```
[sender view].center = loc;
HandleView *handleView = [sender view];

if ([sender view].tag == 0) {
    currentLine.pointA = loc;
    [self DrawLineFrom:loc to:currentLine.pointB];
}
if ([sender view].tag == 1) {
    currentLine.pointB = loc;
    [self DrawLineFrom:currentLine.pointA to:loc];
}
```

}

Any Help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], thanks.